# PDF is downloaded when sending MemoryStream to embed/iframe in view of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to show a pdf in my view that I download from an API, however everytime the view is loaded the browser downloads the pdf instead of showing it inside the `iframe` or `embed`.

I'm getting and returning the pdf in my action like this:

```cs
public FileStreamResult GetPDFInBrowser(Guid id)
{
    string url = A link that gets the pdf from API with id, content is stored as a string inside the "root" object;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string response = client.DownloadString(url);
    Root responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response);
    OOLDocument oolDocument = responseObject.value[0];

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(oolDocument.Contents);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    return File(stream, "application/pdf", oolDocument.FileName); 
}
```

Afterwards I try to show the pdf in my view like this with either `iframe` or `embed`:

```
<iframe src="@baseUrl/GetPDFInBrowser?id=@Model.DocumentsGuid" class="pdfviewer">
</iframe>
<embed src="@baseUrl/GetPDFInBrowser?id=@Model.DocumentsGuid" class="pdfviewer" type="application/pdf" id="pdfObjectViewer">
</embed>
```

So, how do I make sure the pdf is embedded in the browser instead of having the browser download it?

Any help or tips for improving the code are greatly appreciated.

Edit:
With some more searching combined with trial and error I was able to fix the error I was getting and have therefore removed it from the remainder of the question.

For those interested i fixed the error "Cannot load pdf-document" by changing:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(oolDocument.Contents);
```

To:

```
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(oolDocument.Contents);
```

However the pdf is still being downloaded instead of being shown in the view

Comment: `do I make sure the pdf is embedded in the browser`? Well, you don't. It depends on the browser settings of the user and/or (default) setttings of the browser. In my case a PDF wil ALWAYS open in a PDF viewer because I don't like embedded stuff.

Comment: @VDWWD I get that, though for this case I have to embed it. Bosses xD